# Is it possible in mySql to have a user determined path as connection URL

Tags: java, mysql

The connection url which we all use for mySql in java is :-

```
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/THE_DB", "root", "");
```

But I want to know that is it possible to use a url like `C:\\Documents\\Folder\\THE_DB` as the connection URL? If yes, then please tell me what the connection URL would be...

Comment: you don't connect to a db file like in SQLlite. You connect to a DB server, and that exists at very particular spots.

Comment: The format of the URL is determined by the database vendor that you are using. Does you MySQL driver supports a URL like the one you describe?

Comment: I use the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` file as the driver from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/5.0.html. Don't know if it supports that url @EdwinDalorzo

Comment: @puZZlr Then I wonder why you would like to support a URL in that format. And the answer to your question is, of course, in the documentation of your driver which I encourage it to read. As a matter of fact you will see a nice link in that same page you shared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database URL provided in the `getConnection(String url)` method should follow the database driver unified network resource syntax:

> jdbc: subprotocol: subname

Note that each driver may have its own subprotocol and each subprotocol may have its own syntax for the source.